# Algorithm to get all possible permutations of n numbers in a range that have specific sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

What I'm trying to do can be easily illustrated with an example. Assume the following:

```
var minNum = 1;
var maxNum = 30;
var sum = 75;
var amount = 6;
```

I want to get all the permutations of **amount** numbers that add up to sum and are >= minNum && <= maxNum.

For example, if I was to create these permutations by hand, I would start like this:

30,30,12,1,1,1

30,30,11,2,1,1

30,30,11,1,2,1

30,30,11,1,1,2

30,30,10,3,1,1

30,30,10,2,2,1

etc

Is this a known problem in mathematics/programming and are there any algorithms that solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of possibilities in your example is already tremendous, more than hundreds of thousands (I did not do the math, but that is a conservative estimation). The time and space complexity will be challenging to say the least. What do you plan to use this for? NB: there is no fun in programming this, at least not for me.

Comment: Since you're just asking for an algorithm, I think a question like this would be better off asked on the [programmers stack exchange site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @phaze0: Algorithm questions are not off-topic here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh! Good to know.

Comment: Break down that task to two sub-problems. It will be easier to resolve then.

Comment: @trincot Indeed the amount of permutations is extremely large (in the ballpark of millions, not hundreds of thousands). These numbers represent different amounts of a specific substance and the position in the list is basically associated with a weight. A formula comes and uses the weights and the numbers to produce a final result that can be compared against actual experimental data to determine the formula's accuracy.

Comment: sounds like a modified version of the subset sum problem

Comment: This is the problem of **integer partition** into M addends in restricted range accounting for term order. One of the possible algorithms - recursive generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript solution (if your environment recursion depth limits the number of results you would like, you can convert the recursion to an explicit array-stack, push the arguments as would a function call and pop to process them):

```js
function partition(n, min, max, parts) { 
  if (n < 0){
    return;
    
  } else if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += (JSON.stringify(parts)) + '<br>';
    
  } else {
    for (var i=max; i>=min; i--){
      var _parts = parts.slice();
      _parts.push(i);
      
      partition(n-i,min,max,_parts)
    }
  }
}

partition(6,2,4,[])
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```